# How do I tell mypy that a function exits?

Tags: python, types, mypy

If I have a function with a declared return type which exits or returns, mypy is happy:

```py
def f() -> str:
    try:
        return get_str()
    except Exception:
        exit(1)
```

Mypy is happy: the function returns a str, raises or exits.

What about if I want to show an error before crashing?

```py
def die(msg):
    print(msg)
    exit(1)

def f() -> str:
    try:
        return get_str()
    except Exception:
        die("oops")
```

Now mypy isn't happy, because it doesn't know that `die` will kill the program.

1. How do I placate mypy here?
2. Is there some kind of "exits" return type?  (Python has no `Never` so I don't hold out hope)

Comment: @RobinDeSchepper yes, that's a perfect dupe.  Thank you!